# How to enable debugging (breakpoints, stop, inspect variables, continue) with IronPython in a .NET app?

Tags: python, .net, debugging, ironpython

We have a C# .NET application which uses IronPython to support user scripting.  We have an editor we're using, but its not designed for debugging.

It would be nice to allow our users to set breakpoints in a script, be able to stop there, inspect variables, etc.  i.e. basic debugging tasks for scripts which are run from within our app using IronPython.

Any advice on that?

Comment: Have you evaluated/thought about just using an actual .NET debugger (Visual Studio) for that scenario? If the scripts are sufficiently complex this will (in many cases) top any custom debugger/editor and many components you could integrate.

Comment: @SimonOpelt I don't think it would be practical to require our end users to have Visual Studio installed on their machine.  We want to allow users to create/edit/debug scripts they create completely in our application.  So they just install our app and use it.  Having to also have Visual Studio installed would be cumbersome, though, you do have a point it would certainly provide the needed debugging capability.